# Is it possible to ignore individual Blazor/Razor warnings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, razor, blazor, lint

Started working on an existing Blazor project in VS Code today. Shortly after integrating the MudBlazor component library I've noticed that the VS Code linter is complaining about most of the HTML tags due to 'markup element with unexpected name' (RZ10012). It's making an absolute mess of the editor. Adding `@using MudBlazor` doesn't have any impact and everything builds and runs fine.

I've been searching the preferences settings and combing articles about language-based settings but can't seem to find anything that will let me mute this warning by referencing the warning code. Surely there's a simple way to do this - do I need to install a linter that will give me more control over these warnings?

Comment: Did you find a way to suppress it?

Comment: @Ionix No luck I'm afraid. Would be very interested to hear a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just having the same issue in few projects of my solution (RZ10012 warning when @using is properly placed).

For me the solution was to **create the missing _imports.razor file containing the @using directive**.

Placing the @using directive in the file containing the warnings will not solve the problem.